# How to remove blank lines from a BufferedReader

Tags: java

I am trying to get response from a serial modem and store it into BufferedReader. Here is the output:

> imsiAT+CIMI
>   imsi
>   imsi510011130957977
>   imsi
>   imsiOK

and I want to get a value which is *"510011130957977"* with this code:

```
os.print("AT+CIMI");
os.print("\n");                
String responInput20000;             
try {
    while ((imsi = reader.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println("imsi"+imsi);
        txtOutput.insert(imsi.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace("OK", "").replace("AT+CIMI", "")+"\n", 0);
        lblImsi.setText(imsi.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace("OK", "").replace("AT+CIMI", "").replace("\n\r",""));
        if(imsi.equals("OK")){
            break;   
        }
```

but still the `JTextArea` still contains two empty lines. Maybe there is any other solution?

Comment: If your program reads an empty line, then it doesn't ignore it. Just use `imsi.isEmpty()` in your code to check if the read line was empty or not. Btw: you don't need to strip `\n` or `\r` from `imsi`, since it won't be included in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be way easier (and faster) if you wouldn't use the `replace()` method for your needs:

```
while ((imsi = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!imsi.isEmpty() && !imsi.equals("OK") && !imsi.equals("AT+CIMI") {
        txtOutput.insert(imsi);
        lblImsi.setText(imsi);
    }
}
```

There's no need to replace those strings (You can just omit them). And since read with `readLine()` you will not find any newline-characters (`\r\n`) in your string!

Comment: thank you all for respon my answer, i am use the simple way from @ParkerHalo, and it working. i love you stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Matcher to match regular expression (number in this case)

```
    String[] sArr = new String[]{"imsiAT+CIMI","imsi510011130957977","imsiOK"};

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    // or if you know the precise number of digits (15 in example), use this..
    // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{15}");

    String output;

    for (String s : sarr) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            output = matcher.group();
            break;
        } 
    }

    System.out.println(output);
    // or as a number
    long l = l = Long.parseLong(output);

    lblImsi.setText(output);
```

This worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method like this, consuming all reader content and discovering the value you need:

```
private static String getValue(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    String value = null;

    for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {

        String str = line.substring("imsi".length());

        if ("".equals(str)) {
            continue;
        }

        if ("OK".equals(str)) {
            break;
        }

        value = str;
    }

    return value;
}
```